# How to send my model matrix only once per model to shaders

Tags: opengl, matrix, glsl, shader

For reference, I'm following this [tutorial](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/). Now suppose I have a little application with multiple types of model, if I understand correctly I have to send my MPV matrix from the CPU to the GPU (in other words to my vertex shader) for each model, because each model *might* have a different model matrix from one to another.

Now looking at the tutorial and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9503866/how-do-i-display-2-or-more-objects-in-opengl-model-view-projection-matrices), I understand that the call to send the matrix to my shader (`glUniformMatrix4fv(myMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &myModelMVP[0][0])`) **should be done for each frame and for each model** since each time it overwrites the previous value of my MVP (the one for my last model). But, being concerned about the performance of my app, I don't want to send useless data through the bus and if I understand correctly, my model matrix is *constant* for each model.

I'm thinking about having an uniform for each model's MVP matrix, but I think it is not scalable and I would also have to update all of them if my view or projection matrices changed... Is there a way to avoid sending multiple times my model matrices and only send my view and projection matrices upon change?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are essentially two questions: how to avoid sending data when only part of a transformation sequence changes, and how to efficiently supply per-model data which may or may not have changed since the last frame.

#### Transformation Sequence

For the first, you have a transformation sequence. Your positions are in model space. You then conceptually transform them into world space, then to camera/view space, then finally to clip space, where you write the position to `gl_Position`.

Most of these transformations are constant throughout a frame, but may change on a frame-to-frame basis. So you want to avoid changing data that doesn't strictly need to be changed.

If you want to do this, then clearly you cannot provide an "MVP" matrix. That is, you should not have a single matrix that contains the whole transformation. You should instead have a matrix that represents particular parts of the transformation.

However, you will need to do this decomposition for reasons other than performance. You cannot do many lighting operations in clip-space; as a non-linear space, it messes up lots of lighting operations. Therefore, if you're going to do lighting at all, you need a transformation that stops before clip space.

[Camera/view space is the most common stopping point for lighting computations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6672826/734069).

Now, if you use model-to-camera and camera-to-clip, then the model-to-camera matrix for every model will change when the camera changes, even if the model itself has not moved. And therefore, you may need to upload a bunch of matrices that don't strictly need to be changed.

To avoid that, you would need to use model-to-world and world-to-clip (in this case, you do your lighting in world space). The issue here is that you are exposed to the [perils of world space](https://nicolbolas.github.io/oldtut/Positioning/Tut07%20The%20Perils%20of%20World%20Space.html) Numerical precision may become problematic.

But is there a genuine performance issue here? Obviously it somewhat depends on the hardware. However, consider that many applications have hundreds if not thousands of objects, each with matrices that change every frame. An animated character usually has over a hundred matrices just for themselves that change every frame.

So it seems unlikely that the performance cost of uploading a few matrices that could have been constant is a real-world problem.

#### Per-Object Storage

What you really want is to separate your storage of per-object data from the program object itself. This can be done with UBOs or SSBOs; in both cases, you're storing uniform data in buffer objects.

The former are typically smaller in size (64KB or so), while the latter are essentially unbounded in their storage (16MB minimum). Obviously, the former are typically faster to access, but SSBOs shouldn't be considered to be slow.

Each object would have a section of the buffer that gets used for per-object data. And thus, you could choose to change it or not as you see fit.

Even so, such a system does not guarantee faster performance. For example, if the implementation is still reading from that buffer from last frame when you try to change it this frame, the implementation will have to either allocate new memory or just wait until the GPU is finished. This is not a hypothetical possibility; GPU rendering for complex scenes frequently lags a frame behind the CPU.

So to avoid that, you would need to double-buffer your per-object data. But when you do that, you will have to always upload their data, even if it doesn't change. Why? Because it might have changed two frames ago, and your double buffer has old data in it.

Basically, your goal of trying to avoid uploading of sometimes-static per-model data is just as likely to harm performance as to help it.

Comment: Definitely the kind of answer that helped me understand _why_ the issue is probably not an issue and also provides solutions/alternatives at the same time. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it's likely that at least *something* in your scene moves. If it is the objects then the model matrix will change from frame to frame, if it is the camera then the view or projection matrix will change. MVP includes the composition of the three, so it actually will change anyways and you can't get away from updating it in one way or the other.

However, you may still benefit from employing some of these:

- Use [Uniform Buffer Objects](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Uniform_Buffer_Object). You can send the uniforms to the GPU only once, and then rebind the buffer that the program will read the uniforms from. So different models may use different UBOs for their parameters (like model matrix).
- Use [Instancing](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Instancing). Even if you render only one instance of every model, you can pass the model matrix as an instanced vertex attribute. It will be stored in the VAO, and so sent to the GPU only once (or when you have to update it). On the plus side you may now easily render multiple instances of the same model through instanced draw calls.

Note it might be beneficial to separate the model, view and projection matrices. View and projection might be passed through a 'camera description' uniform buffer object updated only once per frame, then referenced by all programs. Model matrix, if it isn't changed, then will be constant within the VAO. To do proper lighting you have to separate model-view from projection anyways. It might look intimidating to work with three matrices on the GPU, but you actually don't have to, as you may switch to quaternion-based pipeline instead, which in turn simplifies such things like tangent space interpolation.

Comment: "it's likely that at least something in your scene moves. If it is the objects then the model matrix will change from frame to frame[...]" Wait, the matrix which describes the model coordinates (the model matrix) changes when the objects in my scene move? I thought it was just the vertices position in my shader that changed (which are model coordinates). For the rest, these are pretty good recommendations, especially the camera description UBO. Also, when having three matrices on the GPU, when I multiply them, isn't it executed once per vertex (in the vertex shader for example)?

Comment: @lordjohncena: model matrix is the one that translate from model coordinates (e.g. those you loaded from a file) to world space (i.e. adjusting the model vertices to account for the position and orientation of the model in the world). So yes -- the way you move the model (e.g. a car) relative to the world (e.g. the terrain) is by modifying its model matrix. The vertex shader is responsible to apply the model matrix to the vertices. Yes it is executed once per vertex.

Answer (score 1):

Two words: **Premature Optimization!**

> I don't want to send useless data through the bus and if I understand correctly, my model matrix is constant for each model.

The amount of data transmitted is insignificant. A 4×4 matrix of single precision floats takes up 64 bytes. For all intents and purposes this is practically nothing. Heck it takes *more* data to issue the actual drawing commands to the GPU (and usually uniform value changes are packed into the same bus transaction as the drawing commands).

> I'm thinking about having an uniform for each model's MVP matrix

Then you're going to run out of uniforms. There's only so many uniform locations a GPU is required to support. You could of course use a *uniform buffer object*, but that's hardly the right application for that.

Comment: Premature optimization, yeah that's a problem I tend to do a lot... I thought it would be something bigger projects would tend to optimize as they would have tons of models.

Comment: I'd definitely put that as the right answer if my question was "Does sending the model matrix each frame for each models alters performance" just because of the hint "[...]uniform value changes are packed into the same bus transaction as the drawing commands", but I wanted to know what kind of approach could solve this as I'm still learning all that stuff.