# Precalculating OpenGL model transformations for static world space

Tags: performance, opengl, gpu

I'm working on an OpenGL visualisation for navigating a 3D dataset. Briefly, the visualisation takes in a large (~1 million data points) array of matrices, which are then eigendecomposed and visualised as ellipsoids.

I have found that performance improves significantly when I calculate ellipsoid vertex transformations "up-front" (i.e. calculate all model transformations once only on the CPU), rather than in shaders (where the model transformations have to be calculated for each draw). For scene navigation/lighting etc., view and projection tranformations are calculated as normal as uniforms passed to the relevant shaders.
The result of this approach is the program taking longer to initialise (due to the CPU being tied up calculating all the model transformations), but significantly higher frame rates.

I understand from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40309914/how-to-send-my-model-matrix-only-once-per-model-to-shaders), that it is common to decompose matrices to avoid unnecessary shader computations, however I haven't come across anything describing this practice of completely pre-calculating the world space.

I understand that this approach is only appropriate for my narrow usecase (i.e. where the scene is static, meaning there will never be a situation where a vertex's position in world space will change while the program is running). Apart from that, are there any significant reasons that I should avoid doing this?

Answer (score 1):

It's a common optimization to remove redundant transformations from static objects. Your objects are static in the world, so you've collapsed all the redundant transformations right up to the root of your scene, which is not a problem.

Having said that, the performance gain you're seeing is probably not coming from the cost of doing the model transform in the shader, but from passing that transform to the shader for each object. You have not said much about how you organize the ellipsoids, but if you are updating a program with the model matrix uniform and issuing a DrawElements call for each ellipsoid, that is very slow indeed. Even doing something more exotic -- like using instances and passing each transform in a VBO -- you would still have the overhead of updating them,which you can now avoid. If you are not doing this already, you can group your ellipsoid vertices into large arrays and draw them with only a few DrawElements calls.